# Mysql Unknown Error

Tags: php, mysql

so basically im trying to check if username is already registered, i have the following code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM verified WHERE summoner = '$summoner'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
{
    $verified = 0;

}
else
{
    $verified = 1;
}
```

I know that mysql_num_row is deprecated as php 5.5.0,
but im using php 5.4.16 and I don't know any alternative way to do that,
Please help me, thanks.

Comment: U forget * . Check a bit your code

Comment: Well, if you don't use `mysql_error()`, you indeed do not know what the error is. (Hint: `SELECT FROM` => select _what_?)

Comment: Profanity is not required. Thanks.

Comment: @Wrikken I use mysql_error() at the end of the document It printed reference id = 17 i Think

Comment: We could need some moderation here

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot something... `SELECT FROM`  Select WHAT from?
add something, a column, a number anything after SELECT, like:

```
SELECT 1 FROM verified WHERE summoner = '$summoner'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM verified WHERE summoner_id = '$summoner->id'");
```

You need to select at least one of your fields, otherwise MySQL is going to choke.

Comment: ill try this:
mysql_query("SELECT summoner FROM verified WHERE summoner = '$summoner'"); and get back to you ;)

Comment: I cant use your code cuz I wanna check if that summoner username has been already verified, so maybe the id's will be messed up so I can't use ID, also: mysql_query("SELECT summoner FROM verified WHERE summoner = '$summoner'"); didn't work and I type random text and verified = 1 (as the result and there wasn't mysql_error())

Comment: I mean without checking your schema, idk if I can answer your question. Did you check that your verified table has a column called summoner, and is looking for the value of $summoner and not maybe an ID?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't selected anything...

Try :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT **SOMETHING** FROM verified WHERE summoner = '$summoner'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
{
    $verified = 0;

}
else
{
    $verified = 1;
}
```

Comment: In this case that should probably be `COUNT(*)` and instead of checking number of rows, get the value and test it vs. 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing a field to select:

```
SELECT SOMETHING FROM
           ^here
```

I guess

```
Select summoner from ...
```